# PHP sort object with usort based on two values

Tags: php, sorting, object, usort, array-multisort

I'm trying to sort my object array based on minimal `SUM`. This is working, but I want to add to my usort function another comparison, which will prefer object, which will have one value true. My objects:

```
object(Basket)[33]
      public 'products' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => 
            object(Product)[13]
              public 'name' => string 'Name ONE' (length=8)
              public 'price' => float 0.75
              public 'exist' => boolean true
          1 => 
            object(Product)[7]
              public 'name' => string 'Name TWO' (length=8)
              public 'price' => float 2.39
              public 'exist' => boolean true
      public 'sum' => float 3.14

object(Basket)[34]
      public 'products' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => 
            object(Product)[19]
              public 'name' => string 'Name ONE' (length=8)
              public 'price' => float 0.75
              public 'exist' => boolean true
          1 => 
            object(Product)[72]
              public 'name' => string 'Name TWO' (length=8)
              public 'price' => null
              public 'exist' => boolean false
      public 'sum' => float 0.75

object(Basket)[35]
      public 'products' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => 
            object(Product)[1]
              public 'name' => string 'Name ONE' (length=8)
              public 'price' => float 0.75
              public 'exist' => boolean true
          1 => 
            object(Product)[2]
              public 'name' => string 'Name TWO' (length=8)
              public 'price' => float 1.75
              public 'exist' => boolean true
      public 'sum' => float 2.5
```

And if I `sort` this, the order is `Basket[34],Basket[35],Basket[33]`.

But I want `Basket[35],Basket[33]` and at the end `Basket[34]`, because he has 1 product, which doesn't exist.

So I want to order based on product existation and then `sort` by `SUM`.
I have this, but it doesn't work:

```
usort($h_basket[$i], function($a, $b) {
    return $a->sum > $b->sum;
});
usort($h_basket[$i], function($a, $b) {
  $unfinded_a = 0;
  $unfinded_b = 0;
  foreach ($a->products as $product) {
    if(!$product->exist) {
      $unfinded_a++;
    }
  }
  foreach ($b->products as $product) {
    if(!$product->exist) {
      $unfinded_b++;
    }
  }
  if ($unfinded_a != 0 || $unfinded_b != 0)
  return $unfinded_b > $unfinded_a;
});
```

Is possible to do this with `usort`, or I have to use `array_multisort`?

Answer (score 0):

To sort by the "exists" field (and I assume the greater percentage of all a carts products that exist, the higher it should be sorted)

I would suggest you use array_filter to get a simple count of how many products have 'exists' vs the total e.g.

```
$exists = count(
    array_filter(
        $object->products,
        function ($product) {
            return $product->exist;
        }
    )
) / count($object->products);
```

Then compare the calculated `$exists` value for the two baskets being compared.

To sort by multiple fields (exists, and then sum) I believe you'll need to call `usort` twice, in *reverse* order - sort by `sum` first **then** by `exists`

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I don't undrestand well. This doesn't work:

usort($h_basket[$i], function($a, $b) {return $a->sum > $b->sum; });
usort($h_basket[$i], function($a, $b) {
      $exists = count(
      array_filter(
          $a->products,
          function ($product) {
              return $product->exist;
          }
      )
    ) / count($a->products);
      $exists2 = count(
      array_filter(
          $b->products,
          function ($product) {
              return $product->exist;
          }
      )
    ) / count($b->products);
      return $exists2 > $exists;
    });